# How I delete docker image?

Tags: docker

Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 529072250ccc (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 5da200b36c1e

How I delete docker image ?

docker ps is Nothing.

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

But I can't delete image.
Commands I have tried

```
docker kill 5da200b36c1e
docker rmi -f 529072250ccc
```

After doing this, the image disappears once but comes back again.

Or sometimes the IMAGE does not disappear.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `docker kill 5da200b36c1e`? Or rebooting the computer?

Comment: KILL does not delete the IMAGE.

Comment: Correct, but your error says you can't delete the IMAGE because there's a CONTAINER running. **So kill the container.**

Answer (score 2):

Check all available containers with `docker ps -a` and see whether the mentioned container with the ID is there. Have a look on its status.

You can try either removing it using `docker rm 5da200b36c1e` or kill it using `docker kill 5da200b36c1e`.

Once it is done, check whether the container is still listed with `docker ps -a` and if so check the status. You may try deleting the image again after this.

Comment: As per the question description, it should be the container ID.

Comment: From the log shown 5da200b36c1e is the container id and 529072250ccc the image id.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the container first:

```
docker stop 5da200b36c1e
```

and then remove the image:

```
 docker rmi -f 529072250ccc
```